# Access Western Digital My Book World II RAID array on my Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, raid, ubuntu-9.10, software-raid

My WD My Book World II (Blue Rings) NAS has overheated, I think the motherboard is dead. I extracted the disks and plugged them in my desktop PC running Ubuntu Linux.

The disks seems to be alive, they are spinning and the BIOS recognize them but Ubuntu is not able to boot as soon as these drives are plugged in. I got an initramfs shell after few minutes telling explaining that the root disk is not available. I suspect that one of my WD drives took the precedence on the system?

Considering that Ubuntu is able to boot and can see my Western Digital disks... is it possible to access the RAID 0 array? How?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `apt-get install dmraid`. Here is [man page](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man8/dmraid.8.php). This could find and import automatically your RAID array. This presumes both devices are found by Ubuntu.